# How can I find a list of all monitored hosts in Nagios-XI after trial expiration

Tags: nagios

I setup Nagios-XI in a VM just to monitor a few mission-critical servers (so less than the limit of 7 hosts...or so I thought). However, apparently one of my coworkers added an 8th host at some point and now all I can is the "License Exceeded" page every time I try to navigate to any thing in the Nagios-XI web console. So, two questions:

1. How can I get a list of all VM's/hosts monitored?
2. How can I remove one of the less important VM's to get us back down to the 7 limit?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

On your VM, you could have a text file which contains the declaration of yours hosts.

This file is in the configuration directory of nagios, or you can do a search with `define host` ([host declaration](https://assets.nagios.com/downloads/nagioscore/docs/nagioscore/3/en/objectdefinitions.html))

When you will find this file, you will be able to delete all the text in the brackets

Comment: Thank you, @Sorcha. Do you know where this file lives.../etc/ maybe?

Comment: It depends of your distribution and your installation. But you can try here `/usr/local/nagios/etc/`. Also, you can search the file nagios.cfg (`find / -iname nagios.cfg`). Yours configuration files will be in the same directory or in a sub-directory